# How do you input Java char's into MYSQL database and then also retrieve them as well?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc, char

I am using a MYSQL database to store persisted data for a java application.

```
CREATE TABLE testtable1( key1a CHAR, key1b CHAR, encoded1a CHAR, encoded1b CHAR);
```

As you can see i create a table that stores for each row a 4 different CHAR's.

the sql i have written for inputing the chars into the table is

```
 char k1[] = new char[2]
 char p[] = new char[2];

 k1[0]=0x00aa;
 k1[1]=(char)0xaaaa;

 p[0]=0x0001;
 p[1]=0x0002;

sql = "INSERT INTO testtable1 "
                +"(key1a, key1b , encoded1a,encoded1b) "
                + "VALUES "
                + "('"+ k1[0] + "',"
                + "'"+ k1[1] + "',"
                + "'"+ p[0] + "',"
                + "'"+ p[1] + "')";
```

The above statement i dont think work. it inpts the data as such
[image]

And then into the database like this
[image]

So as you can see, it is been inputed with a ?(whatis this?) and then the final two columns are not being populated.

So could any of you guys point me in the right direction to where my thinking is wrong when it comes to storing char variable.

And also , how would i retrieve the chars from the database table? as i cannot find any Doc's on this???

thank you very much

Comment: You want to store a `CHAR` but you have a `char[]` in java...why?

Comment: this call to k1[0] will return a char variable. It will go to the index number in the char array and return a char variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

An example would be as follows:

```
PreparedStatement ps = nulll;
try {
    ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO testtable1 (key1a, key1b , encoded1a,encoded1b) VALUES (? ,? ,?, ?)");
    for (int i = 1; i <= k.length; i++) {
        ps.setString(i, "" + k[i]);
    }

    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException) {
    //Log exception
} finally {
    if (ps != null) {
        try {
            ps.close();
            ps = null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
}
```

The problem here is that if `char[]k`'s length is greater than 4, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: "First of all, a char in java is a byte value of range [0..255]"  No it isn't, a char is a two-byte, UTF-16 value.

Comment: @R Bemrose, yeah, thanks...found it...I removed my statement.

Comment: the data is being inputed as a ? still, any ideas why ? also how would i go about reading the char from the database?

Comment: @molleman, I'm assuming you're doing a select from the console. The console can only display ASCII characters only.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `PreparedStatement` answer:

Java's `char` is a 16-bit `UTF-16` value.

MySQL's `CHAR` is a synonym for `CHAR(1)`... which is just a single character wide, (number of bytes depends on the table's character set).

Now, `PreparedStatement`'s `setString` *should* take care of the encoding conversion for you, but that still leaves one problem: MySQL on some systems defaults to the `latin1` character set.  Which means `CHAR` is too small.

There is a fix for this.  During table creation, you can force a table to be a specific character set:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable1( key1a CHAR, key1b CHAR, encoded1a CHAR, encoded1b CHAR) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Note: You can also use `utf16` instead of `utf8`; I just used `utf8` for storage size reasons.